# Cannot listen to any TCP port on macOS Big Sur with app Proxifier: protocol wrong type for socket

Tags: macos, sockets, tcp, macos-big-sur

### Environment

- macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29)

  - System Firmware Version: 1554.50.3.0.0 (iBridge: 18.16.12561.0.0,0)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019) (`MacBookPro15,1`)
- Using [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/) (edit: resolved because of this. see answer below)

```sh
$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 20.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.1.0: Sat Oct 31 00:07:11 PDT 2020; root:xnu-7195.50.7~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

### Problem

When tried to listen to any TCP port (tried TCP ports like `1`, `80`, `5555`, `10000`, `60000`) system complains

```
Protocol wrong type for socket
```

Where specifically, with `netcat`:

```
$ nc -v -l 5555
nc: listen: Protocol wrong type for socket
```

and with Go code (`go version: go version go1.13.7 darwin/amd64`):

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"
)

func main() {
    _, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":80")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

```
$ go run main.go
panic: listen tcp :80: listen: protocol wrong type for socket
```

Any help will be much appreciated! I can't do any development now on my Mac :(

Answer (score 3):

Ummmm ok this is embarrasing... Turns out that all of this is because I'm using [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/). Quitting the app resolved this problem.

I'll leave this here for anyone who fallen in this lol. :D

Update: Proxifier seems to be aware of this issue (see [here](https://www.proxifier.com/download/bigsur/)). Turns out to be *"a bug in Network Extension API"* and Apple haven't been fixing it since September...

### Workarounds proposed by Proxifier ([ref](https://www.proxifier.com/download/bigsur/))

- Start affected applications before Proxifier start
- Or bind the socket to `127.0.0.1`, not to `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem has been fixed by Apple in Big Sur 11.1 beta.
The bug affects all applications that use NETransparentProxyProvider.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661610

It is not a fault of Proxifier.

Answer (score 0):

But it is a proxifier bug, since it should leave Direct connections alone - which it doesn't.

Comment: It seems they've aware of this problem. See [here](https://www.proxifier.com/download/bigsur/)